# Testing MS ODBC SQLReturn values

Tags: sql, winapi, odbc

Can these values (returned from calls like `SQLGetConnectAttr`) be tested for success/failure using standard WinAPI `FAILED`/`SUCCEEDED` macros to avoid checking individual values? If not are there special SQL variants of those macros?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such macro exists. `SQLxxx()` functions returns various values and it depends from application if retured value indicate success or failure . One example of such value is `SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND`. Is it success or failure? In my opinion it depends of application and context.